# ansible docker postgres volume

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker, ansible, infrastructure

i am doing some postgres deployment with docker, ansible and terraform in aws

things are going relatively well, i start the instance with terraform, provision the instance with docker using ansible, start my postgres container with ansible also, and attach a ebs volume to my instance, which i intend to use as the main data storage.

but i am confused as to how to attach the volume to the docker (not to the instance as i am able to do that using terraform)

i imagine it is possible using ansible or modifiying the dockerfile, but the documentation of the "**volume**" which seems to be the answer is not that clear to me.

so if i had an ansible playbook like this:

```
name: Start postgis
docker_container:
name: postgis
image: "{{ ecr_url }}"    
network_mode: bridge
exposed_ports:
  5432
published_ports:
  5432:5432
state: started
```

how would i specify the ebs volume to be used for the data storage of Postgres?

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "ebs-volume-postgis-attach" {
device_name = "/dev/xvdh"
volume_id = "${aws_ebs_volume.ebs-volume-postgis.id}"
instance_id = "${aws_instance.postgis.id}"
}
```

that was the code used to attach the ebs volume, in case someone is interested

please ask any kind of info that you need, all help is deeply apreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a checklist:

1. Attach EBS volume (disk) to EC2 instance (e.g. `/dev/xvdh`)
2. Make partition (optional) (e.g. `/dev/xvdh1`)
3. Make filesystem on the partition/disk
4. Mount filesystem inside your EC2 instance (e.g. `/opt/ebs_data`)
5. Start Docker-container with volume (e.g. `/opt/ebs_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`)

In Ansible's `docker_container` module, `volumes` is a list, so:

```
- docker_container:
    name: postgis
    image: "{{ ecr_url }}"    
    network_mode: bridge
    exposed_ports:
      - 5432
    published_ports:
      - 5432:5432
    state: started
    volumes:
      - /opt/ebs_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was missing the "make filesystem" step,

one quick question:
defining the volume is : "ebs_storage_path:postgres_data_dir" correct?

Comment: alright, this works now, one detail: it doesnt work if you use the root of the mounted volume as directory, you must use some subdirectory
(example: /opt/ebs_data/postgres), i believe it is worth mentioning in your answer